# Alter main archive, to show posts with meta as last

Tags: custom-field, query, meta-query, order

I'm having troubles with getting posts with meta_value "sold" as last in the main query of my custom Post type.

The best/easiest way i can think of at the moment is to filter the "sold" posts out of the main query, and add a custom query with only "sold" posts in the template. But to be honest, this seems so ugly and there should be a better/cleaner way.

Does any of you have experience with something like this? And how did you solve it? Would love to think of a better way to solve this.

Thanks!

Alright, i got some code working, but still don't think this is te best way to do this, so any tips and hints are very much welcome.

```
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'sold_at_last' );
function sold_at_last( $posts_array ) {

$at_start = array();
$at_end = array();

if ( is_post_type_archive('objects') ||
     is_tax( 'object_type' ) ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) {
            $status = get_field( 'status', $post->ID );

            if ( $status == 'Verkocht' ) {
                $at_end[] = $post;
            } else {
                $at_start[] = $post;
            }
        }
    }
}

$new_posts_array = array_merge( $at_start, $at_end );

if ( ! empty( $new_posts_array ) ) {
    return $new_posts_array;
} else {
    return $posts_array;
}}
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you don't show the code you are talking about.

Comment: Well the code isn't there atm, its a main archive with the archive-posttype.php template. Which atm just has the main layout.